# Is serialVersionUID still necessary?

Tags: java, serialization

I've read the other questions about implementing serializable, and I'm still not clear on why its necessary to set a serialVersionUID (besides the performance bonus).

If I set the serialVersionUID to another value and try to restore the persisted data I'll get `Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: Point; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6698220721129043078, local class serialVersionUID = -2587313359772143387`

But if I match up the UID and change the y int to a double instead, it gives the same exception, but now more meaningful
`Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: Point; incompatible types for field y`

What kind of incompatible change wouldn't cause an InvalidClassException?

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Point implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6698220721129043078L;

  private final int x;
  private final int y;

  public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Point{" + "x=" + x + ", y=" + y + '}';
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Point point = new Point(5, 7);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("object.dat");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(point);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();

    // FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("object.dat");
    // ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    // Point point = (Point) ois.readObject();
    // System.out.println(point);
    // ois.close();
    // fis.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: @user16320675 how can I modify my code to demonstrate that?

Comment: @user16320675 that has no effect on the output, which is always `Point{x=5, y=7}`

Comment: @user16320675 im just telling you what I've observed after trying to change the order. Have you tried it?

Comment: then just change the variable name(s), e.g. `private final int x; private final int z;` (or the meaning of any variable contents)

Comment: I think yes, because the serialVersionUID to facilitate versioning of serialized data.

Comment: @user16320675 adding or removing fields doesn't create a problem, but changing the name does. Thank you